# How to change scrollview or flatlist indicator(scroll bar) color?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I want to change scrollbar or indicator color which appears on right side of a list in case of vertical scroll. Can someone point towards appropriate props? I didn't find any in docs other than `indicatorStyle` which is not useful in my case as it supports only enum. I want to give a red color to my scrollbar/scroll indicator.

Note: I'm using React-native for app development, not native android coding.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white"
```